# Where I can find Gita-mahatmya in original devanagari script (7 slokas in Devanagari script) from Introduction to Bhagavad-gita of Srila Prabhupada

Tags: bhagavad-gita, sanskrit, resource

> (1)
>   gītā-śāstram idaṁ puṇyaṁ  yaḥ paṭhet prayataḥ pumān
>   viṣṇoh padaṁ avapnoti  bhaya-śokādi-varjitaḥ
>
> (2)
>   gītādhyāyana-śīlasya  prāṇayama-parasya ca
>   naiva santi hi pāpāni  pūrva-janma-kṛtāni ca
>
> (3)
>   mala-nirmocanaṁ pumsāṁ  jala-snānaṁ dine dine
>   sakṛd-gītāmṛta snānaṁ  saṁsāra-mala-nāśanam

etc

rest is in the end of [introduction](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/introduction).

According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padma_Purana), it is from Uttarakhanda of Padma Purana, but where is it exactly?